# How to avoid runtime error with themecolor

Tags: excel, vba

At some point in a macro I want to remove all my comments done in my cells using green text.

For this I simply use 2 "for" loop:

```
For Each WS In WB.Worksheets
For Each cell In WS.UsedRange.Cells

    If cell.Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3 Then
        cell.Value = ""

    End If
Next
Next
```

But some times the themecolor seems not defined and the code stop with a runtime error '5' Invalid procedure call or argument.

I have tried to find a solution by myself. As I have many others colours I can't set a default value for every cells.

How can I avoid this run time error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's simply to avoid it, you can create some not so good kind of try-catch (wich doesn't exist in VBA), like this:

```
    For Each WS In WB.Worksheets
        For Each cell In WS.UsedRange.Cells

            on error goto 1
            If cell.Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3 Then
                cell.Value = ""

            End If
1           on error goto 0

       Next
    Next
```

Comment: If I may, I would recommend `On Error Resume Next [do code] On Error Goto 0`.

Comment: What is the purpose of goto 0 ? where is 0 ?

Comment: I still don't know the purpose of "go to 0", I think a "On error resume next would do better"

Comment: This `goto 0` means you are no longer treating any errors. That is VERY different from `resume next`, wich means you are IGNORING errors.
With `goto 0`, the next errors will stop execution as they should do. With `resume next`, you will never know if any error occurs after the region of your concern.

Comment: The comment written by joseph4tw is good, but it replaces the `goto 1`, not `goto 0`.